# Setup Client/Server setup for qemu/kvm

Tags: server, client, centos7, qemu, kvm

Server : server should have one nic for internet access and other to communicate to clients

```
RAM: 4 GB
CPUs: 2
nic 1 : NAT
nic 2 : host only but dont knw subtype Bridge,VEPA, private etc
storage : 20 GB
```

Client: should be able to connect to server but should not have internet access

```
RAM: 2 GB
CPUs: 1
nic : host only dont need internet access just need to download yum and pip packages
storage: 10GB
```

progress so far
Created Server and Client Machines im not getting ip for hostly only NIC

Server:
NIC 1 : NAT i get the ip for this one and im also able to ping 8.8.8.8

```xml
<interface type="network">
  <mac address="52:54:00:e2:39:72"/>
  <source network="default" portid="15a8afb0-12fa-43d6-8bbe-c1509c6dae82" bridge="virbr0"/>
  <target dev="vnet0"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net0"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

NIC 2: HOST ONLY im not getting ip for this one

```
<interface type="direct">
  <mac address="52:54:00:c7:1c:99"/>
  <source dev="vmnet1" mode="bridge"/>
  <target dev="macvtap0"/>
  <model type="virtio"/>
  <alias name="net1"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x02" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</interface>
```

cannot paste images aparantly need 10 rep i cannot use clipboard on minimal vms :(

Comment: Both server and client are running inside VM?
You want to have internet access inside server but disconnect clients from internet?
Please take a look at VSOCK for communication between VMs.

Comment: thanks i created a virtual adapter (isolated network) by clicking on edit network connection details the vms are connected to each other by this network adapter
and seprate bridge adapter for vm1 to connect to public network for internet i was able to do this via gui still not confident on how to   edit the xml files to alter network properties